# Javascript Function toLocaleString() Mongo DB not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid, mongo-shell

On mongo shell we are trying to format output values for comma separated . but mongo shell doesnt format the value.

Mongo Function On Shell:

```
db.system.js.save({_id:"testValue", value: function(){ 
            var number2 = 1234.56789;
            valueFormatted=numer2.toLocaleString(); 
             return valueFormatted }
})
```

output:  1234.56789 (* no effect of function)

Why is `.toLocaleString()` not working in mongo shell ?
Is any other way of formatting numbers to comma separated within in mongo functions ?

Comment: Why do you think you even need JavaScript functions on the server? Their execution via `eval()` is deprecated ( read "will be removed soon" ) and most other utility of JavaScript execution has already been superseded by native operators. Or indeed things that *really should be done* in your implementation language instead.

Comment: It might not format because there is a typo in `numer2.toLocaleString()`. I think you meant `number2`?

Comment: @NeilLunn.. Formatting numbers through programmatic iterations over the list is not idea, for our current scenario. may be if database can give formatted output, that would avoid further processing on UI or in Implementation.

Comment: @Codeer.. its a typo , but issue is still same

Comment: I suggest you actually listen and realize that executing JavaScript within MongoDB is going to "cease to exist" some time in the future. `eval()` is near gone, `group()` is gone and eventually `mapReduce()` support is likely to go as well. So expecting the database to continue running this code is not a path you should be headed down. Also not a database's job to do presentation formatting. That's a job for a client.

Comment: @NeilLunn.. That was a try :-) . Thanks for advice. I can always go back to client side formatting. Do you think Javscript executions in mongodb is time consuming and expensive compared to that doing in client-side(on browser) or programmtically

Answer (score 0):

You can use date format command

```
 db.system.js.save({_id:"testValue",
 date: { $dateToString: { date: new Date(), format: "%Y-%m-%d"} } })
```